# OSX Flush DNS without sudo

Tags: macos, applescript, dns, sudo

I have a Mac that keeps messing up its DNS (this may be a wider network issue, we have windows clients that are having problems too). Whilst I try to understand the DNS issue I'd like to set an 'icon' (app/script) for my customer to be able to click that will flushdns as this resolves the immediate issue.

Unfortunatly flushing DNS needs to elevate. Is there a way to flushdns without sudo.

Alternatively, how do I get automator/applescript to prompt for and accept elevated credentials when double clicked by a user (to then execute a dns flush command in bash?)

Comment: U could create a new user group, add certain users to it, and allow the group to use a certain command

Comment: @fartheraway I'm from the Windows world - can you point to documentation or any examples of how to do this?